# Нужна ли запятая перед тире?

Tags: пунктуация

За исключением редукторов, в России практически нет производств, а если есть, то цена не ниже европейских, даже при нынешнем курсе, — и это печально.

Все, что можно заменить, — надо заменять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю,что запятые нужно оставить.

Тире здесь авторское, обозначает дополнительную паузу при присоединении или противопоставлении, поэтому постановка знаков препинания должна быть независимой.

Answer (score 0):

Запятые-то на месте, да...

> *"За исключением редукторов, в России практически нет производств, а если
> есть, то цена не ниже европейских,
> даже при нынешнем курсе, — и это
> печально."*

Может, так:

*"В России практически не производятся необходимые для таких-то нужд редукторы, а если и производятся, то цена их не ниже европейских даже при нынешнем курсе евро, — и это печально."* ?

**P.S.**

Или речь должна идти о чём-то другом?

> *Нет. Тут же как раз говорится, что редукторы производятся. Поэтому если
> только "За исключением производства
> редукторов, в России практически нет
> производств, а если есть, то цена не
> ниже европейских, даже при нынешнем
> курсе, — и это печально". Но тогда
> получается масло масляное.*

То есть, смысл должен быть примерно таким:

*"За исключением редукторов, в России практически никаких других комплектующих [для того-сего] не производится, а у тех, что производятся, цена не ниже европейских даже при нынешнем курсе евро, — и это печально."* ?

Comment: Нет. Тут же как раз говорится, что редукторы производятся. Поэтому если только "За исключением производства редукторов, в России практически нет производств, а если есть, то цена не ниже европейских, даже при нынешнем курсе, — и это печально". Но тогда получается масло масляное.

Comment: Alenka: "...в России практически нет производств, а если есть, то цена не ниже европейских".=== ЦЕНА ПРОИЗВОДСТВ ?

Comment: Думаю, цена товаров, которые они производят. Это из контекста.

Answer (score 0):

Причём здесь тире? Следует избегать таких "громоздких" фраз. 
За исключением редукторов, в России практически нет производств, а если есть, то цена не ниже европейских, даже при нынешнем курсе.  И это печально.